# How can I generate a post preview url in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, preview

I would like to generate the preview url for a post outside of wordpress admin (wp-admin).

Normally this link is available while editing the post, but I would like to generate it to display on the frontend (a page only accessible by admin).

How can I generate this link using the `$post->ID`? Note: `preview_post_link` filter is only for changing the url, whereas I need to actually create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's quite easy using `get_preview_post_link()` like:

`get_preview_post_link($post = null, $query_args = array(), $preview_link = '' )`

This is in `wp-includes/link-template.php`

Comment: I simply can't get this to work. I added a link like this: `<a href="<?php echo get_preview_post_link($post->ID) ?>" target="wp-preview-<?php echo $post->ID ?>">Preview</a>` which produces an identical link to the built-in "Preview Changes" link. But clicking mine just shows the published post - not the changes I've made. I have no idea what to do differently. Feels like there must be some JS at play behind the scenes to make the built-in "Preview Changes" do its thing?

Comment: @powerbuoy can you confirm that your `$post->ID` is a valid ID?

Comment: Yea it's definitely a valid post ID, and the preview page does work and shows the correct post, only it doesn't contain any of the changes I've made to the post. It shows the old post. If I disable JS and click the built-in "Preview"-button that behaves the same way so there's definitely some AJAX going on in the background to generate a new revision when you hit the built-in button.

Answer (score 0):

We use a plugin called "Public Post Preview" to allow preview of author books before going live. Works great and author keeps it up-to-date.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-post-preview/

Basically you tick the box to allow public review and use the link supplied by the plugin. Not much more to it than that.

The only draw back is preview only works for 48 hours. You can of course modify the time limit using authors instructions.